# call sql scripts from a trigger

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, triggers

I am using Oracle Data Miner on 11g in Windows 8. I want to create a trigger which will instantiate some sql scripts when it is executed (i.e. whenever I am trying to insert or update a record)
The trigger hence will call some sql scripts. The whole purpose of this is to do some process when I am adding tuple in the table. I cannot get the correct syntax for it.
I tried using

```
create or replace trigger startClassification
after insert or update on comorbidity_scores
for each row
begin
@"C:\path\to\script\workflow_drop.sql";
@"C:\path\to\script\workflow_run.sql";
end;
```

But its not working.
What will be the correct syntax?

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: Are you aware that those script must be on the **server** where Oracle is running? Plus `@` is a SQL*Plus command, you can't use that inside PL/SQL (or even SQL)

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Interesting stuff, that XY problem. So, the question is : what problem is the poster trying to solve ? He or she doesn't know that Oracle doesn't like external code. External to the database, obviously includes the filesystem it runs on. -

Comment: I eventually found out that writing triggers and scheduling a db query would be completely different tasks. Yeah, it turned out to be XY problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.
the problem was to start some process (data mining process here) when I add record in database participating in my workflow system in Oracle Data Miner.
I used DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION and DBMS_SCHEDULER in a PL/SQL procedure.
TRIGGERS on the other hand I wrote independently.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UTL_FILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i996873) to read the file with SQL script and execute it with [DBMS_JOB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm#BABHCBFD) (if you have just one statement in the script then use [EXECUTE IMMEDIETE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm).

Just be aware that this is a really serious backdoor (anyone with the write access can run queries in your DB!).